# Classify a list of value through a list of thresholds

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, double, threshold

I have a map of `<String,Double>` considered as thresholds to classify a list of Doubles

```
HashMap<String, Double> map = new Hashmap<>();
map.put(A/B,0.7);
map.put(B/C,0.4);
map.put(C/D,0.3);
map.put(D/E,0.1);
```

The Doubles of the hash is used as threshold to classify a list doubles given, so I want to transform this map into a list of classes A, B, C, D

```
Class A : from 0.7
Class B : from 0.4 to 0.7
Class C : from 0.3 to 0.4
Class D : from 0.1 to 0.3
Class E : less than 0.1
```

Do you have any idea on how to perform that as a method `StringClassifyByValue(HashMap<String, Double> map, Double value){}` returning a String of the class correspondent of the value given as parameter?

ِExample :

`this.StringClassifyByValue(map,0.5)` have to return B.

Comment: I love the concept, thank you so much for your advices and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thoughts: first of all, your data structure is not really helping with the problem you want to solve. But that is exactly what data structures exist for: to give you a helpful abstraction that allows you to efficiently solve your "most important" problem.

Coming from there, I would suggest that you start by creating classes that **better** fit your problem statement. You could start with something like

```
public class Interval {

   private final double lowerBoundary;
   private final double upperBoundary;

   public Interval(double lowerBoundary, upperBoundary) {
     this.lowerBoundary = ...
   } 

   public boolean contains(double value) {
     return (value >= lowerBoundary) && (value <=upperBoundary);
   }
```

And instead of keeping of using a `Map<String, Double>` you rather have something like `List<Pair<Classification, Interval>>` where:

- `Pair` could be a class that simply holds two values that belong together (instead of using a "generic" pair class, you could also create your own custom class that *combines* a `Classification` with an `Interval`).
- `Classification` represents a "class", like A, B, C, in your example. The point is: be careful about using raw String objects for such purposes. Maybe a simple string is fine for now, but maybe you have to further enhance your logic later on - to then find that "hm, now a simple string doesn't do any more, but now I have to update a ton of places to change that".

And of course: ideally, you would **sort** the above list by "intervals". Then finding the `Classification` for a specific double value is super simple:

```
 for (Pair<Classification, Interval> combo : listOfPairs) {
   if (combo.getInterval().contains(value)) {
     return combo.getClassification(); // yeeha found one
   }
 }
 return "nothing found" ... or throw some kind of exception
```

Long story short: I can't tell you how to best *transform* your existing map into the above list of pair objects - because I don't know the big picture. It might be possible to simply *not* create that map initially, and directly build such a list of objects.

And for the record: if that map exists as map because there are *other*, more important requirements ... then you have to carefully balance if you really want to keep using map+list (means "double book-keeping") or if you put all of the above logic into some service that turns your Map into a List, does the lookup and then throws away this "other" representation of your data.

Comment: Thank you so much GhostCar of your contribution, finaly I found a solution very sample without creating a new class of boudaries interval juste with split with regex "/" and make boudaries from the previous and current elements. I will share it with the public, thank you very much for you help

Answer (score 1):

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> getMinMaxThreshold(HashMap<String, Double> map) {

        List<Double> threholds = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        HashMap<String,Double >map1= this.sortByValues(map);
        List<String> keys = map1.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        Collections.sort(threholds);
        Collections.reverse(threholds);

        HashMap<String, HashMap<String,Double>> boudaries = new HashMap<>();


        for (int i =0;i<=threholds.size();i++){

            if(i==threholds.size()){
                HashMap<String, Double> testmap = new HashMap<>();
                testmap.put("max",threholds.get(i-1));
                testmap.put("min",0.0);
                boudaries.put(keys.get(keys.size()-1).split("/")[1], testmap);
                System.out.println(threholds.get(i-1)+" ->"+0+" : "+keys.get(keys.size()-1).split("/")[1] );
            }

            else if (i==0){
                HashMap<String, Double> testmap = new HashMap<>();
                testmap.put("max",Math.exp(1000));
                testmap.put("min",threholds.get(i));
                boudaries.put(keys.get(0).split("/")[0], testmap);
                System.out.println(Math.exp(100) +" ->"+threholds.get(i)+" : "+keys.get(0).split("/")[0] );}

            else{
                HashMap<String, Double> testmap = new HashMap<>();
                testmap.put("max",threholds.get(i-1));
                testmap.put("min",threholds.get(i));
                boudaries.put(keys.get(i).split("/")[0], testmap);
            System.out.println(threholds.get(i-1)+" ->"+threholds.get(i)+" : "+keys.get(i).split("/")[0]);}
        }

        System.err.println(boudaries);

        return boudaries;
    }
```

1. The ’keys’ is a ’List’ and represent the Classes A,B,C,D.
2. The thresholds is a ’List’represent the thresholds. We have
   to use this threshold to make the boundaries.
3. I sort the map of thresholds by values to get the Strings in descending order, and same with the list of Double thresholds to make them in the same order.
4. I loop foreach element of threshold.. for the first item it's about the last boudaries so I made as boudaries the Exp(1000) and the previous element.. for the last element, it's about a boudaries with min 0 and max the last element of threshold.
5. I use split to get the first element of splited array except the last item where I use the second element of the array to match the last element. That's it

Test :

If we have as an input this ’Map’

```
{ "YELLOW_DARK/RED_LIGHT" : 0.20459770114942527 , "GREEN_DARK/GREEN_LIGHT" : 0.6226151930261519 , "GREEN_LIGHT/YELLOW_LIGHT" : 0.4632936507936508 , "YELLOW_LIGHT/YELLOW_DARK" : 0.3525246305418719 , "RED_LIGHT/RED_DARK" : 0.027777777777777776}
```

My code will transorm it into :

```
2.6881171418161356E43 ->0.6226151930261519 : GREEN_DARK
0.6226151930261519 ->0.4632936507936508 : GREEN_LIGHT
0.4632936507936508 ->0.3525246305418719 : YELLOW_LIGHT
0.3525246305418719 ->0.20459770114942527 : YELLOW_DARK
0.20459770114942527 ->0.027777777777777776 : RED_LIGHT
0.027777777777777776 ->0 : RED_DARK
```

and returning as a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>`

```
{GREEN_LIGHT={min=0.4632936507936508, max=0.6226151930261519}, YELLOW_DARK={min=0.20459770114942527, max=0.3525246305418719}, YELLOW_LIGHT={min=0.3525246305418719, max=0.4632936507936508}, RED_DARK={min=0.0, max=0.027777777777777776}, RED_LIGHT={min=0.027777777777777776, max=0.20459770114942527}, GREEN_DARK={min=0.6226151930261519, max=Infinity}}
{ "GREEN/LIGHT_YELLOW" : 0.5366379310344828 , "YELLOW_DARK/RED_LIGHT" : 0.18349195937745413 , "YELLOW_LIGHT/YELLOW_DARK" : 0.3571428571428571 , "RED_LIGHT/RED_DARK" : 0.08940809968847352}
```

Comment: Nice addendum :-)